# Pandas read_csv fails

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using pandas read_csv to open a csv file 1327x11. The first 265 rows are only 4 columns wide. Here is row 1 to 5

`DWS_LENS1.converter,"-300.0,5.5; -0.1,5.5; 10.0,-5.5; 300.0,-5.5",(mass->volts),:  DWS_LENS1.mass_dependent,false,:
DWS_LENS1.voltage.reading,-5.12642,V,:
DWS_LENS1.voltage.target,-4.95000,V,: 
DWS_LENS2.converter,"-300.0,20.0; -10.0,20.0; 10.0,-20.0; 300.0,-20.0",(mass->volts),:`

and here are some other rows :

`157955,SAMPLE,,,,1760.5388,,,,:
,: 
Summary,:
,: 
Analyte,H3O+ (ppb),NO+ (ppb),O2+ (ppb),O- (ppb),OH- (ppb),: 
toluene,1872.7367,,,,,: 
isobutane,,1945.7385,,,,:
hexafluorobenzene,,,1951.0644,2121.6486,,:
tetrafluorobenzene,,,,,1599.5802,:`

I receive Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 266, saw 11

I tried 
`df=pd.read_csv(test,error_bad_lines=False)`

but it skips most rows and returns a 491x4 table.

If I use `pd.read_csv(test,delim_whitespace=True,error_bad_lines=False)`

I obtain a 1300x4 table but it fails splitting some data.

How can I have the 11 columns back?

Comment: Are you sure the default delimiter for `pandas.read_csv` is correct?

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the file?

Comment: I don't think you can read this file in into a data frame. You need to first determine what you want form the data, and then read the data into a different file. Your first like (with a ") has 4 rows. Your second line has 3. The line that says summary has 2. The line that contains toluene contains 7 lines. Dataframes contain data such that each column has the same type of information. You might need to split the file into different sections before you  use Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

add this : `lineterminator = ':'`

Comment: It does not help, I still have 4 columns only.

Comment: i just dont understand what the data looks like. post a line amigo